# Solution for Finding Total Number of Computer-Generated Passwords

Tags: combinatorics

May I have help with the step-by-step on this?

1. Computer-generated four-letter temporary password (no numbers/digits)
2. Assuming upper and lower; not specified

What is the process/formula and answer for this please? Similar questions either were not clear to me or included numbers and/or special characters.

Comment: What ideas do you have? :) (Hint: How many options do you have for each letter of the password?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for posing this question. If you have a four letter password then you have four spaces, each of which can take on 26 different characters:

_. _. _. _.

So that leads to:

26*26*26*26

If you include capital letters then those are distinct characters as well, so now that is still four spaces, but each one with 52 characters:

52*52*52*52

Therefore, the total number of possible combinations is $52^{4}$

Comment: Thanks @EvanGertis!